# How to convert RTF file to PDF

Tags: windows, pdf, conversion, rtf

Looking to convert a simple RTF file into PDF.

Is there a way to do this without 3rd party software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would open the RTF in Windows-Wordpad and print to PDF using the "print as  PDF file" printer driver.

[image: Wordpad and Print to PDF]

<sup>This creates a PDF file without doing any actual printing</sup>

Comment: I dont have a printer though. As the question states, im looking to convert the file.

Comment: Also, what is windows write?

Comment: I meant Wordpad. The PDF printer driver doesn't print, it saves as a PDF file. Its an odd but effective way of converting RTF to PDF

Comment: I see you updated your answer (i took the time to explain things a little more in dpeth. I will still award you the answer. Thanks for helping out! If you think the question will be helpful to other users, please feel free to upvote the question.

Answer (score 2):

If MS Word is installed on your PC, you could use it to save the rtf file as pdf using "Save As" then selecting PDF. A pdf document will be created based on the rtf document.

Comment: doesnt seem to be installed.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to user [RedGrittyBrik](https://superuser.com/users/52492/redgrittybrick) who helped this answer come to be. Im going to take a little time to make this answer a little more user friendly.

So to easily convert an RTF file to PDF we simply open the file in Windows-Wordpad and then click on the Print option in the File menu in the top left corner:

[image]

Next, select the 'Print to file' option, then select 'Microsoft Print to PDF (you may have to use the scrollbar to navigate to the left) **Note:** this will not actually require a printer. It is simply going to save a file.

[image]

The hit 'Apply' and then 'Print' at the bottom of the dialog box. Another window will pop up asking you where you would like to save the file while giving you the option to rename it.

Comment: There's no need to checkmark "Print to file". Printing to PDF is, by definition, printing to file in the first place, and the MS Print to PDF driver's smart enough to know it. No harm to choosing Print to File ... just no need.

Answer (score 1):

Just for sharing, I made a powershell script that will install right click context menus to convert documents (.doc,.docx,.rtf,.odt,.pdf) to oneclick conversion to other formats. (Needs Microsoft Office MSI based installation, 2007+, works for inactivated versions too). Execute the script and click Install to get them. Then right click RTF document, hover on Convert To at bottom and click PDF. It will appear on the current location. Tested with MS office 2013 and 2007:

```
# Word2AnyInstall.ps1
#This script will install context menus on .DOC,.DOCX,.RTF,.PDF,.HTM,.HTML,.ODT,.XML,.XPS files to convert them to different # format using MS Word
#   Right-click any file in these extensions and you will get a menu abiove "Properties" use it
#   An MSI-based (not Click-To-Run) installation of MS Office is required, will work for Office 2007+ versions and even # Unactivated versions will work too
#   While conversion, just make sure that MS Word is not Open and please don't occupy C:\bin directory where files will be kept

$currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
if( -not ($currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)))
{
    Write-Host "Running Admin Shell, Please wait....."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)`"" -Verb RunAs
    Exit 0
}

function Install {
If (!(Test-Path C:\bin)){
  New-Item C:\bin -Type Directory
}

@'
Param(
    [System.IO.Fileinfo]$Source,
    [String]$Format
)
$arrFileExt = @{
     "doc"      =   0
     "docx"     =   0
     "htm"      =   8   
     "html"     =   8
     "odt"      =   23
     "pdf"      =   17  
     "rtf"      =   6
     "txt"      =   4
     "xml"      =   19
     "xps"      =   18
}
$myFileType = $arrFileExt."$Format"
$myFileName = $Source.Basename
$myFileExt = "." + $Format
$toSave = Split-Path "$Source"
$myOutputFile = $toSave + "\" + $myFileName + $myFileExt
$objWord = New-Object -COMObject "Word.Application" 
$objWord.Visible = $False
$objWord.Documents.Open([string]$Source) | Out-Null
$objDoc = $objWord.ActiveDocument
$objDoc.SaveAs("$myOutputFile",$myFileType) | Out-Null
$objDoc.Close() | Out-Null
'@ | Set-Content C:\bin\Word2Any.ps1

@'
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo]
"MUIVerb"="Convert To"
"Position"="Bottom"
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\001DOC]
"MUIverb"="Word document 1997-2003 (DOC)"
"Icon"="%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\WINWORD.exe,-2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\001DOC\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"doc\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\002DOCX]
"MUIVerb"="Word document 2007-2019 (DOCX)"
"Icon"="%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\WINWORD.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\002DOCX\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"docx\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\003PDF]
"MUIVerb"="Portable Document Format (PDF)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe,13"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\003PDF\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"pdf\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\004RTF]
"MUIVerb"="Rich Text Format (RTF)"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\004RTF\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"rtf\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\005ODT]
"MUIVerb"="Open Document Text (ODT)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe,3"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\005ODT\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"odt\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\006TXT]
"MUIVerb"="Plain Text File (TXT)"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,70"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\006TXT\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"txt\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\007HTM]
"MUIVerb"="HTML webpage (HTM)"
"Icon"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
  00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,49,00,6e,00,74,00,65,00,72,00,6e,00,\
  65,00,74,00,20,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,69,\
  00,65,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,\
  35,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\007HTM\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"htm\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\008HTML]
"MUIverb"="HTML webpage ()HTML)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe,17"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\008HTML\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"html\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\009XML]
"MUIVerb"="XML File (XML)"
"Icon"="ieframe.dll,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\009XML\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"xml\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\010XPS]
"MUIVerb"="XPS File (XPS)"
"Icon"="D:\\Windows\\System32\\xpsrchvw.exe,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\010XPS\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"xps\""






[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo]
"MUIVerb"="Convert To"
"Position"="Bottom"
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\001DOC]
"MUIverb"="Word document 1997-2003 (DOC)"
"Icon"="%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\WINWORD.exe,-2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\001DOC\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"doc\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\002DOCX]
"MUIVerb"="Word document 2007-2019 (DOCX)"
"Icon"="%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\WINWORD.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\002DOCX\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"docx\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\003PDF]
"MUIVerb"="Portable Document Format (PDF)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe,13"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\003PDF\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"pdf\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\004RTF]
"MUIVerb"="Rich Text Format (RTF)"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\004RTF\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"rtf\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\005ODT]
"MUIVerb"="Open Document Text (ODT)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe,3"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\005ODT\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"odt\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\006TXT]
"MUIVerb"="Plain Text File (TXT)"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,70"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\006TXT\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"txt\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\007HTM]
"MUIVerb"="HTML webpage (HTM)"
"Icon"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
  00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,49,00,6e,00,74,00,65,00,72,00,6e,00,\
  65,00,74,00,20,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,69,\
  00,65,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,\
  35,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\007HTM\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"htm\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\008HTML]
"MUIverb"="HTML webpage ()HTML)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe,17"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\008HTML\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"html\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\009XML]
"MUIVerb"="XML File (XML)"
"Icon"="ieframe.dll,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\009XML\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"xml\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\010XPS]
"MUIVerb"="XPS File (XPS)"
"Icon"="D:\\Windows\\System32\\xpsrchvw.exe,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\010XPS\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"xps\""









[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo]
"MUIVerb"="Convert To"
"Position"="Bottom"
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\001DOC]
"MUIverb"="Word document 1997-2003 (DOC)"
"Icon"="%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\WINWORD.exe,-2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\001DOC\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"doc\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\002DOCX]
"MUIVerb"="Word document 2007-2019 (DOCX)"
"Icon"="%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\WINWORD.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\002DOCX\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"docx\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\003PDF]
"MUIVerb"="Portable Document Format (PDF)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe,13"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\003PDF\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"pdf\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\004RTF]
"MUIVerb"="Rich Text Format (RTF)"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\004RTF\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"rtf\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\005ODT]
"MUIVerb"="Open Document Text (ODT)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe,3"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\005ODT\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"odt\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\006TXT]
"MUIVerb"="Plain Text File (TXT)"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,70"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\006TXT\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"txt\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\007HTM]
"MUIVerb"="HTML webpage (HTM)"
"Icon"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
  00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,49,00,6e,00,74,00,65,00,72,00,6e,00,\
  65,00,74,00,20,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,69,\
  00,65,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,\
  35,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\007HTM\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"htm\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\008HTML]
"MUIverb"="HTML webpage ()HTML)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe,17"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\008HTML\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"html\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\009XML]
"MUIVerb"="XML File (XML)"
"Icon"="ieframe.dll,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\009XML\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"xml\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\010XPS]
"MUIVerb"="XPS File (XPS)"
"Icon"="D:\\Windows\\System32\\xpsrchvw.exe,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo\shell\010XPS\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"xps\""




[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo]
"MUIVerb"="Convert To"
"Position"="Bottom"
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\001DOC]
"MUIverb"="Word document 1997-2003 (DOC)"
"Icon"="%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\WINWORD.exe,-2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\001DOC\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"doc\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\002DOCX]
"MUIVerb"="Word document 2007-2019 (DOCX)"
"Icon"="%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\WINWORD.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\002DOCX\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"docx\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\003PDF]
"MUIVerb"="Portable Document Format (PDF)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe,13"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\003PDF\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"pdf\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\004RTF]
"MUIVerb"="Rich Text Format (RTF)"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\004RTF\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"rtf\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\005ODT]
"MUIVerb"="Open Document Text (ODT)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe,3"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\005ODT\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"odt\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\006TXT]
"MUIVerb"="Plain Text File (TXT)"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,70"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\006TXT\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"txt\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\007HTM]
"MUIVerb"="HTML webpage (HTM)"
"Icon"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
  00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,49,00,6e,00,74,00,65,00,72,00,6e,00,\
  65,00,74,00,20,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,69,\
  00,65,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,\
  35,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\007HTM\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"htm\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\008HTML]
"MUIverb"="HTML webpage ()HTML)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe,17"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\008HTML\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"html\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\009XML]
"MUIVerb"="XML File (XML)"
"Icon"="ieframe.dll,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\009XML\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"xml\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\010XPS]
"MUIVerb"="XPS File (XPS)"
"Icon"="D:\\Windows\\System32\\xpsrchvw.exe,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo\shell\010XPS\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"xps\""





[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo]
"MUIVerb"="Convert To"
"Position"="Bottom"
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\001DOC]
"MUIverb"="Word document 1997-2003 (DOC)"
"Icon"="%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\WINWORD.exe,-2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\001DOC\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"doc\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\002DOCX]
"MUIVerb"="Word document 2007-2019 (DOCX)"
"Icon"="%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\WINWORD.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\002DOCX\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"docx\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\003PDF]
"MUIVerb"="Portable Document Format (PDF)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe,13"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\003PDF\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"pdf\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\004RTF]
"MUIVerb"="Rich Text Format (RTF)"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\004RTF\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"rtf\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\005ODT]
"MUIVerb"="Open Document Text (ODT)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe,3"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\005ODT\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"odt\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\006TXT]
"MUIVerb"="Plain Text File (TXT)"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,70"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\006TXT\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"txt\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\007HTM]
"MUIVerb"="HTML webpage (HTM)"
"Icon"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
  00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,49,00,6e,00,74,00,65,00,72,00,6e,00,\
  65,00,74,00,20,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,69,\
  00,65,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,\
  35,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\007HTM\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"htm\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\008HTML]
"MUIverb"="HTML webpage ()HTML)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe,17"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\008HTML\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"html\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\009XML]
"MUIVerb"="XML File (XML)"
"Icon"="ieframe.dll,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\009XML\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"xml\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\010XPS]
"MUIVerb"="XPS File (XPS)"
"Icon"="D:\\Windows\\System32\\xpsrchvw.exe,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo\shell\010XPS\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"xps\""





[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo]
"MUIVerb"="Convert To"
"Position"="Bottom"
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\001DOC]
"MUIverb"="Word document 1997-2003 (DOC)"
"Icon"="%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\WINWORD.exe,-2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\001DOC\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"doc\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\002DOCX]
"MUIVerb"="Word document 2007-2019 (DOCX)"
"Icon"="%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\WINWORD.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\002DOCX\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"docx\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\003PDF]
"MUIVerb"="Portable Document Format (PDF)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe,13"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\003PDF\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"pdf\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\004RTF]
"MUIVerb"="Rich Text Format (RTF)"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\004RTF\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"rtf\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\005ODT]
"MUIVerb"="Open Document Text (ODT)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe,3"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\005ODT\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"odt\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\006TXT]
"MUIVerb"="Plain Text File (TXT)"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,70"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\006TXT\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"txt\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\007HTM]
"MUIVerb"="HTML webpage (HTM)"
"Icon"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,20,\
  00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,49,00,6e,00,74,00,65,00,72,00,6e,00,\
  65,00,74,00,20,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,69,\
  00,65,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,\
  35,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\007HTM\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"htm\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\008HTML]
"MUIverb"="HTML webpage ()HTML)"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe,17"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\008HTML\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"html\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\009XML]
"MUIVerb"="XML File (XML)"
"Icon"="ieframe.dll,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\009XML\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"xml\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\010XPS]
"MUIVerb"="XPS File (XPS)"
"Icon"="D:\\Windows\\System32\\xpsrchvw.exe,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo\shell\010XPS\command]
@="powershell.exe -file C:\\bin\\Word2Any.ps1 \"%1\" \"xps\""

'@ | Set-Content C:\bin\wordsav.reg

regedit.exe /s C:\bin\wordsav.reg
}

function Uninstall {

@'
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\ConvertTo]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\ConvertTo]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.RTF.8\shell\ConvertTo]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.OpenDocumentText.12\shell\ConvertTo]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgePDF\shell\ConvertTo]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSEdgeHTM\shell\ConvertTo]

'@ | Set-Content uninstall.reg

regedit /s uninstall.reg
Remove-Item C:\bin\Word2Any.ps1
Remove-Item C:\bin\wordsav.reg
Remove-Item C:\bin
}
[Console]::WindowWidth = 192
[Console]::Title = "Word2AnyInstall"
@'
################################################################################################################################################################
                       
                                                          Word2AnyInstall.ps1
   This script will install context menus on .DOC,.DOCX,.RTF,.PDF,.HTM,.HTML,.ODT,.XML,.XPS files to convert them to different format using MS Word
   Right-click any file in these extensions and you will get a menu abiove "Properties" use it
   An MSI-based (not Click-To-Run) installation of MS Office is required, will work for Office 2007+ versions and even Unactivated versions will work too
   While conversion, just make sure that MS Word is not Open and please don't occupy C:\bin directory where files will be kept

################################################################################################################################################################

'@
$msg = @'

[1] Install
[2] Repair
[3] Uninstall

'@
choice /c 123 /n /m $msg
switch ($LastExitCode) {
1 {Install}
2 {Install}
3 {Uninstall}
}

Write-Host "`nDone!"
Read-Host
```